# PHP MVC: Where should I put the model searching logic?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I'm building a MVC PHP framework from scratch, and I have some problems regarding the model layer.

What I have right now is a relatively basic MVC implementation, here's my entry point ( index.php ):

```
//get the URI
$uri = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) 
           ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
           : '/';
//Initializes the request abstraction from URI
$request = new request($uri);

//getting the view class from the request
$viewFactory = new viewFactory();
$view = $viewFactory->getView($request);
$view->setDefaultTemplateLocation(__DIR__ . '/templates');

//getting the data mapper from the connection string
$connectionString = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;username=root;";
$dataMapperFactory = new dataMapperFactory($connectionString);
$dataMapper = $dataMapperFactory->getDataMapper();

$modelFactory = new modelFactory($dataMapper);

//getting controller and feeding it the view, the request and the modelFactory.
$controllerFactory = new controllerFactory();
$controller = $controllerFactory->getController($request,$view,$modelFactory);

//Execute the necessary command on the controller 
$command = $request->getCommand();
$controller->{$command}($request);

//Produces the response
echo $view->render();
```

I think this is self explanatory, but if you don't get something, or if you think I did some horrible mistake, feel free to tell me.

Anyway, the modelFactory is in charge of returning  whatever model the controller could require. I now need to implement the "model research" logic, and in my opinion there's two ways of doing it:

First way: Implementing a modelSearch class containing all research logic, then make my model inheriting it ( like in Yii2 ). I don't like this method because it would make me instantiate some model and have it returning other instance of itself. So I have the same model instantiated once to research and once ( or more ) with all datas, and no use of search methods.
so my controller would look like that:

```
class site extends controller{

    public function  __construct($view, $modelFactory){
        parent::__construct($view, $modelFactory);
        /* code here */
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $searchModel = $this->modelFactory->buildModel("exemple");
        $model = $searchModel->get(["id"=>3])->one();
        $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Second way: Implementing a modelSearch class containing all research logic, then in the entry point, instead of instantiating the modelFactory, I could istantiate the modelSearch, and feeding it the dataMapper. Then I give the modelSearch to the controller, and the controller would get any model he wants by asking the modelSearch ( which would use the modelFactory to instantiate models and return them ), like that:

```
class site extends controller{

    public function  __construct($view, $searchModel){
        parent::__construct($view, $searchModel);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $model = $this->searchModel->get("exemple",["id"=>3])->one();
        $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

This way seems more correct to me, but has the disadvantage of having to call the modelSearch class to return any model, even empty ones.

Thoughts?

TL;DR: modelSearch: Do I use it as independant tool to get models, or do I make models inherit from it?

Comment: Yeah no. That's not hoe you set up MVC. TBH, I am not even sure what "search logic" is based on your examples. The abstraction of search should go in the responsible service instance, which then would internally deal with the abstraction of result collection and retrieval of that collection from using various persistence abstractions.

Answer (score -1):

Searching logic should be within the model itself as the MVC describes model,view & controller. Model should have only one responsibilities that is work with database itself. While as controller should be responsible for manipulating of data and passing the data.

Comment: Indeed. The model is a layer though, so the question is about the searchModel class: Do I use it as independant tool to search and return models, or do I make models inherit from it?

Comment: For the small search returning the models would be great but for the larger and complex search making a search as a independent module would be better.

Comment: Controller should not be responsible for "manipulating and passing data". An model layer is a lot more complicated then just a dumb database abstraction.

Comment: controller should act as  a bridge between model and view means model grabs a data controller passes it to the view then on wards

Answer (score -1):

First read any MVC pattern PHP framework as CI, CakePHP and YII, and then you will see the model (how it works with database). and you can create there self model searching logic and you can see YII framework for best searching logic in model and usability in controllers.

Comment: Yii use statics methods in their models. I don't like it, as instantiated models will also have those methods, without ever using them. 
Is this the optimal way to go? Isn't it better to put research logic in another class?

Comment: Learning MVC from php frameworks is like learning medicine from a homeopath, or quantum physics from Deepak Chopra.